# How to simulate a movie?

Tags: matlab, loops, signal-processing

Let us consider the following code (`fs` is sampling frequency)

```
function [] = AR_simulate(p,fs)

B = xlsread('data_generations1','A1','g8:g301');
for k = 1:1:p
    [pxx,f] = pyulear(B,k);
    plot(f,pxx);
    F(k) = getframe;
end
movie(F,100);

end
```

which animates the power spectral density of a given `B` vector with different orders, namely from order `k=1` to `k=p`.

Now I want to save each picture somewhere, but on each picture I would like to include the parameter `k`, for example at `k=1` there was this picture, at `k=2` there was different picture and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will put the title of each frame as `k=1`, `k=2` etc. and will print each frame as an eps file to `Frame1.eps`, `Frame2.eps`, etc.

```
function []=AR_simulate(p,fs);
B=xlsread('data_generations1','A1','g8:g301');
 for k=1:1:p
     [pxx,f]=pyulear(B,k);
     subplot(1,2,1)
     plot(f,pxx);
     F(k) = getframe;
     title(['k=' num2str(k)])
     subplot(1,2,2)
     % 2nd plot
     print('-depsc2',['Frame' num2str(k) '.eps')
 end
 movie(F,100);
end
```

You can also use [text](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/text.html) instead of title to place the text anywhere on the plot.

Comment: also please  how can i do so that when k=p,stop movie?

Comment: It will save in your current working directory. I'm not sure off hand how to stop the movie, but I'm sure if you check the documentation it will be obvious.

Comment: thanks David(in georgia this name is as Davit),ok thanks very much,just one question using subplot,i can show other power spectral estimation methods in loop right?like periodogram and so on

Comment: Yes you can do all sorts of things in a subplot, a different type of plot should be fine.

Comment: just one example using periodogram if you can  please to include in code,just one example

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what a periodogram is! I edited my answer to show the use of subplot, but I can't help any more than that, sorry.

Comment: thanks thanks  it is enough,about subploting,how it is counting by the way,subplot(1,2,1),subplot(1,2,2),then subplot(1,3,1) like this?

Comment: For `subplot(a,b,c)`, `a` is the total number of rows of plots, `b` is the total number of columns, and `c` is the `c`-th subplot, going along rows first. So if you wanted 3 subplots in one row, you would do `subplot(1,3,1)`, `subplot(1,3,2)` and `subplot(1,3,3)`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, [`getframe`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) with zero input arguments captures a frame based on the current *axis*. If you want to capture a frame based on the figure, including a title and the axes ticks, you need to do `getframe(gcf)`.  Alternatively, use `text` as suggested by @David to place the label on the axes you capture.

Regarding saving of the images, you can use [`frame2im`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/frame2im.html) and `imwrite`, in the loop just after `getframe`:

```
im = frame2im(F);
imwrite(im,sprintf('im_k%03d.png',k))
```

Or to save the frames to a movie, use the [`VideoWriter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter-class.html) class and call [`writeVideo`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.writevideo.html) on every iteration.